Get rid of empty listview when disabled
Hiall, may i know how to get rid of my listview becomes empty when i disabled it.
This is the listview when enabled
This is the listview when disabled

That's just the way it behaves. In Access it is easier to use a Subform in Datasheet view. E.g. see: Create a form that contains a subform.

Only display the headers when the listbox is enabled:
Me!YourListBox.ColumnHeads = Me!YourListBox.Enabled

or hide it completely:
Me!YourListBox.Visible = Me!YourListBox.Enabled


ListBox ≠ ListView
